# pdfmake как сделать цикл

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть библиотека под названием pdfmake, так вот, вывод текста в pdf файл делается следующим образом:

```
{
  text: "текст 1 строки"
},
{
  text: "текст 2 строки"
}
и тд...
```

Как видите, для того, чтобы написать текст с новой строки нужно взять его в {} скобки

Так вот, у меня есть **двумерный** массив **a[N][0]** и **a[N][1]** с **N** количеством значений, например:

```
a[0][0] = "Hello";
a[0][1] = "World";
a[1][0] = "I am";
a[1][1] = "array";

и тд...
```

Как мне вывести все значения массива в формате **a[N][0]: a[N][1]**, чтобы каждое из них было на отдельной строчке?
Должно быть что-то вроде:

```
{
  text: "Первая строка"
},
for (var i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
  {
    text: a[i][0] + ": " + a[i][1]
  },
}
```

В итоге выполнения этого js скрипта должно вывести:

```
Hello: World
I am: array
```

Заранее Спасибо

Comment: `a.map(line => { return {text : line}})`?

Comment: Да, спасибо, но как сделать тоже самое, только с Двумерным массивом? `a[0][0] = "Hello"; a[1][0] = "World"` И если можно, пояснить, я в jquery (да и вообще в js) не силен, что такое map и line

Comment: В свете уточнения вопроса: ```a.map(line => { return {text : `${line[0]} : ${line[1]}`}})```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let a=[]
a[0] = "Hello";
a[1] = "World";
a[2] = "I";
a[3] = "am";
a[4] = "array"
let PDFobject=a.map(line=>{return [{text:line}]})
console.log(PDFobject)
```

Метод `.map` вызывает переданную первым параметром функцию для каждого элемента массива и возвращает новый массив, состоящий из возвращённых этой функцией значений с каждой из итераций. В функцию передаются три аргумента, с которыми мы можем работать: значение, ключ и сам массив ([документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)). Дак вот, `line` является переменной, в которой хранится значение с каждой итерации массива, её название может быть любым. Ещё оптимальнее эта строчка кода могла выглядеть так: `a.map(text=>[{text}])`, это чудеса синтаксиса JSа, если интересует, могу и её объяснить.

---

```js
let a=[
  ['Сколько копыт у пони?','4'],
  ['Какое любимое лакомство Селестии?','Тортики'],
  ['Как называется бутик Рарити в Понивилле?','Карусель']
],
PDFobject=a.map(v=>({text:v[0]+': '+v[1]}))
console.log(PDFobject)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82266/discussion-on-answer-by-diskyp-pdfmake---).